# Angular 14: Problem with routing to child route

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

In my Angular 14 application I have tree on the left side which contains buildings and persons inside these buildings.

```
    + Building 1
       - Person 1
       - Person 2
       - Person 3
    + Building 2
       - Person 4
       - Person 5
```

When I click an entry in the tree I want to display some details on the right side of the browser window. Therefore, I created a HTML template which contains the tree and a `<router-outlet>` for rendering the child components.

```html
      <div class="container">
        <div class="tree-container">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="content-container">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The routes are defined in this way:

```js
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
        children: [
          { path: 'building/:uuid', component: BuildingComponent},
          { path: 'person/:uuid', component: PersonComponent},
        ]
      },
    ];
```

When I click an entry I call a method in the MainComponent routing to the corressponding child compoment:

```js
    this.router.navigate(['building', buildingUuid], {relativeTo: this.route})

    or

    this.router.navigate(['person', personUuid], {relativeTo: this.route})
```

This works in that the details are loaded on the right side. Unfortunately, with each click on a tree item, the tree on the left side is also reloaded what causes all expanded nodes to be collapsed. ngOnInit of the main component which contains the tree is called on every click.

Any ideas, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am having the same issue.